# Rails translation missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

in my rails applictaion (Rails 4.2.X) I got the following error:

[image]

Mysterious is when I reload the page twice or three times the page loads normally ... what could be the problem?

Update:

[image]

Update:
[image]

Comment: It seems that the german base translations are missing. If you can print out the I18n.locale for the non-failing requests and it's not "de", that is it.

Comment: Can you see a date: -> format: -> short: key in your translation file?

Comment: @rewritten What do you mean exactly? sorry didn't got it.

Comment: @lcguida i've added a screenshot of the german translation file

Comment: Hum, for you message error, you're actually trying to translate a Time object. Where is the part of your translation file that has time formats? (and not the date part) ? Somehting like: `time:
    am: am
    formats:
      default: "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"
      long: "%B %d, %Y %H:%M"
      short: "%d %b %H:%M"`

Comment: @lcguida oh sorry I've added the wrong part. I've added the correct one above. Whats a bit mysterious is when I reload the page several times it works fine ... Its only the first time I call the page

Comment: does passanger go to sleep mode or something like that?

Comment: no more ideas? problem still active ...

Comment: ?? is there noone with a great idea?